# Steps to authenticate WebGet REST Service in c#.net

Tags: c#, wcf-rest

To this WebGet REST Service [URL](http://localhost:51152/WebService.svc),Is there any steps to authenticate in c#.net?

Comment: the link is to your localhost so of course no one can enter...

Comment: yes,i need to know the steps to provide user authentication to this type of REST (GET method) URL

Answer (score 0):

There a lots of way to pass user authentication within a REST GET - as you have no body (as it's a GET) you can pass something in the Url, eg: /myWebService/GetAllUser?token=some-encrypted-token-or-guid

or 
you can pass something in the headers; use cookies etc. 
A lot depends on the client.

The query-string token might be the easiest option?